# C# finding text by listview and giving it a backcolor

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, backcolor

I want to find a certain string (text) that is entered in the textBox1 field in the listView1. So the current problem is, the code below works however right next to the item which has its backcolor changed, the other item would have the same backcolor when hovered over. And when the row is selected then hovered over, there is change in colors (the dark blue goes a bit light when hovered).The listView is kept inside a tabControl. 
Any ideas why the item next to it gets the backcolor? Any solutions would be great.

```
foreach (ColumnHeader sColumnHeader in listView1.Columns)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem items in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (items.SubItems[sColumnHeader.Index].Text == textBox1.Text)
        {
            listView1.Items[items.Index].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
            listView1.Items[items.Index].SubItems[sColumnHeader.Index]
                                        .BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
         }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the problem screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7H7E.png

Comment: try to set listView1.Items by actual number (listView1.Items(0).SubItems[sColumnHeader.Index]
                                        .BackColor = Color.LightBlue;) not in for each use index 0 for that and tell me the result

Comment: Hi there,setting item as listView1.Items[0].SubItems[sColumnHeader.Index] .BackColor = Color.LightBlue; does not remove this problem

Comment: no, just tell me which item has changed? first one or second one?

Comment: Oh sorry! the second one

Comment: Added a link to the initial post where the backcolor is deeppink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the activation on the listView being on "OneClick".

Resetting it back to Standard fixed this problem.

Sorry and thanks to everyone who has helped.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** Use this Code

```
       foreach (ColumnHeader sColumnHeader in listView1.Columns)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                if (item.SubItems[0].Text == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    listView1.Items[item.Index].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                    listView1.Items[item.Index].SubItems[0]
                                                .BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No error at all. The item just goes to the one before it. I think we have to look at the columns.

Comment: Yay! Make sure you place the code above under the textBox1_TextChanged event. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi there, this updated answer does not work also as it checks for items in the first column. In your test, put in 4 random columns and run the code above (put your text in the textBox to some item in the 2nd column) then highlight the third column to see it has the same colour for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

[This is not really meant as an answer, but it's too long for a comment]

Your code as shown works perfectly for me -- the subitem that matches the text in textBox1 has its background changed to LightBlue. If the colour changes on selection or hovering, that has nothing to do with this particular bit of code.

Obviously, if you have `FullRowSelect` set to `true`, the background will change when the row is selected.

BTW, you should use much less indexing -- instead just iterate the `Items` and `SubItems` collections:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems) 
    {
        if (subItem.Text == textBox1.Text)
        {
            item.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
            subItem.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that. FullRowSelect is set to true. Yes the colour does change when the item is selected. However, when I leave the item (where the text equals the subitem), the colour goes to a lighter shade of blue then when I hover back, it goes back to the dark blue colour. The problem I have is that when the subItem Text equals the textBox1 text, the back colour changes but the subItem next to the one who has the back colour changed, when hovered over, also has its back colour changed to LightBlue (but it does not show unless you hover over).